# What is this error and how do I fix it? Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow script I'm trying to run, and every time I run it I get this error, and Google hasn't helped me figure out the cause.

**Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)**

Thanks for any help.

Here's a more extensive error message.

```
2021-12-22 20:04:43.518831: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-12-22 20:04:44.339137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5490 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2021-12-22 20:04:49.923774: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8301

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: `0xC0000409` is `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`.  That's a tough one from Python.  About all you can to is triple-check all of your array shapes, and make sure you're not asking for matrix sizes that you aren't providing.  And that's a kernel error code.  Are you using a GPU?  Sure your Nvidia driver is up to date?

Comment: Did you compile tensorflow yourself?

Comment: My Nvidia driver is up to date. If it's an array shape issue, do you know how I could go about troubleshooting which part of the code has the size or what not that's causing the error?

Comment: Standard installation via pip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. It's an error unique to incompatibilities between certain versions of CUDA and CUDAnn, in my case I had to just keep switching out the CUDNN files until I found one that worked (8.2)

Comment: Thank you, had the same problem and your solution worked for me too.